# How to Increment the cell index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to read the data (key&value) from excel and check whether the given data is present in a dictionary or not.
Example for excel :

```
key       value
====      =====
v54      desktop
v7         nav
events    event6
```

When I tried the following code it gives me only the current row

OUTPUT:

```
Key-value pair found in dictionary events : event6
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
Key-value pair found in dictionary v54:desktop
Key-value pair found in dictionary v7:nav
Key-value pair found in dictionary events : event6
```

```py
for index in range (len(df)):
   key = df.loc[index,'key']
   value = df.loc[index,'value']

if key in dict and dict[key] == value:
    print("Key-value pair"" "+color.GREEN+"found"+color.END+ " ""in dictionary"" "+color.GREEN+ key +" : "+ value+color.END)
    df.at[index, 'result'] = 'PASS'
    
else:
    print("Key-value pair"" "+color.RED+ "not found"+color.END+" " "in dictionary"" "+color.RED+key +" : "+ value+color.END)
    df.at[index, 'result'] = 'FAIL'
        

# Save the updated dataframe to the Excel file
df.to_excel('test.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Perhaps your indentation is wrong? My guess is the if-else branch should be inside the loop. You might be able to use vectorial/more idiomatic pandas/numpy code by doing something like `np.where(df["key"].map(dict) == df["value"], "PASS", "FAIL")`, but you'd miss out on the intermediate printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong. it should be like this :

```
for index in range (len(df)):
   key = df.loc[index,'key']
   value = df.loc[index,'value']

    if key in dict and dict[key] == value:
        print("Key-value pair"" "+color.GREEN+"found"+color.END+ " ""in dictionary"" "+color.GREEN+ key +" : "+ value+color.END)
        df.at[index, 'result'] = 'PASS'

    else:
        print("Key-value pair"" "+color.RED+ "not found"+color.END+" " "in dictionary"" "+color.RED+key +" : "+ value+color.END)
        df.at[index, 'result'] = 'FAIL'


# Save the updated dataframe to the Excel file
df.to_excel('test.xlsx', index=False)
```